# All emails with an attachment shows as plain text since last composer update

Tags: php, email, laravel, attachment, swiftmailer

Yesterday I did a composer-update to make Laravel Debugbar work, but today I found a big problem.

Every single email that I send out with Laravel and has an attachment get's buggered up. With buggered up I mean that the email doesn't show as HTML anymore, and the entire email content shows as plain text. Before the update it all worked perfectly fine.

I tried several internal functions to attach the file like file_get_contents and then attach with attachData but nothing helps.

The dividers show up as well, as well as part headers like encoding and content type:

```
--=_swift_v4_1416930602_4b48853874e4571583469e0f8bf178d7e6cb24dd=_
```

How I send the email:

```
Mail::send('emails.master', $data, function($email) {
    // Set from, to...
    $email->attach(Request::root() . '/quotepdf/' . Input::get('quoteId') . '/download', array('as' => 'Quote #' . Input::get('quoteId') . '.pdf', 'mime' => 'application/pdf'));
});
```

My attachment shows as a base-64 encoded string, which seems to be correct.
Any ideas?

If I just take a file on the fs, and attach that as an attachment, I have the exact same problem.
Only *without* attachment the email shows as normal HTML.

Pastebin of the email I received: http://pastebin.com/NFYUVqGP

Comment: Don't have a definitive answer for you, but I know that playing with the mail settings helps sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I ended up doing a clean Laravel installation and moving over all controllers, views, models etc etc. Nothing helped till the point that I was wasting my time.